# Toggle Class not working Properly, I want to add active class on click and show content of clicked list ONLY in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using [ngClass] to add the active class to show/hide content on click. Adding the class is working fine, but the problem is, on click its opening all other list items as well. what I want is to show details of the list that is being clicked and not another list. how do I fix my this as i do not want to user id or RefEelment.

Thanks

**HTML**

```
    <ul class="list-group panel-list-group list-group-inactive">
    <li class="list-group-item>
        <div class=" p-a-panel (click)="onShowDetails()">
        <div class="CollapseDetails" [class.active]="isOpen">
            <h3>Customer Details1</h3>
        </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="list-group-item>
        <div class=" p-a-panel (click)="onShowDetails()">
        <div class="CollapseDetails" [class.active]="isOpen">
            <h3>Customer Details2</h3>
        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**TypeScript**

```
     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-admin-customer-central',
      templateUrl: './admin-customer-central.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./admin-customer-central.component.css']
    })
    export class AdminCustomerCentralComponent implements OnInit {
      isOpen = false;
    
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    
      
      onShowDetails() {
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
    }
   }
```

**CSS**

```
    .CollapseDetails {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .active{
      display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that each of your panels are looking at the same property to determine whether or not they should be open.

One approach to fixing this would be to create a new model that holds information about each particular panel. For instance:

```
export class CollapsiblePanel {
  heading: string;
  body: string;
  isOpen: boolean;
}
```

Then you can create an array of collapsible panel objects in your view model:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CollapsiblePanel } from 'src/models/collapsible-panel-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-customer-central',
  templateUrl: 'src/admin-customer-central.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['src/admin-customer-central.component.css']
})
export class AdminCustomerCentralComponent implements OnInit {
  panels: Array<CollapsiblePanel> = [
    { heading: 'Collapsible Heading 1', body: 'Collapsible Body 1', isOpen: false}
    { heading: 'Collapsible Heading 2', body: 'Collapsible Body 2', isOpen: false}
    { heading: 'Collapsible Heading 3', body: 'Collapsible Body 3', isOpen: false}
    ];

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onShowDetails(panel) {
    panel.isOpen = !panel.isOpen
  }
}
```

And loop through them in your view:

```
<ul class="list-group panel-list-group list-group-inactive">
  <li *ngFor="let panel of panels">
     <div class="p-a-panel" (click)="onShowDetails(panel)">
        {{ panel.heading }}
        <div class="CollapseDetails" [class.active]="panel.isOpen">
            <h3>{{ panel.body }}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Since your CollapsiblePanel data structure keeps track of each individual panel's collapsed state, they can collapse/expand independent of each other.

Check out this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/EHW45z56tfn5pXnG4CQd?p=preview